# A patch of water that is part of a shapefile is painted as land

Tags: shapefile, openmap

So I've set up [OpenMap](http://openmap-java.org/) in a Java application, but the default world map shapefile **(dcwpo-browse.shp)** that comes with OpenMap wasn't sufficient enough, since the area I specifically needed wasn't fully drawn in this default file.

Which is why I ended up using a shapefile that I found somewhere on the internet. But OpenMap seems to want a **.ssx** file accompanying the **.shp** file, but this other shapefile doesn't. And many other shapefiles I still have to use don't have a **.ssx** file either, and some of them don't even display on the OpenMap MapBean at all.

And even though this new map shapefile works, it seems like it just fills every shape, even the one that is actually supposed to stay transparent because it's water. This is probably because it's an enclosed area due to a bridge that is drawn, which makes that particular area appear like another piece of land. And I can't help but wonder whether it might be because I lack the .ssx file, or because of something else.

What's the best way to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: I'd be very surprised, if this was the result of a missing .ssx file, because the .ssx is just a spatial index, which is used to improve performance.
Did you check, if your new shape file is correct, e.g. by examining it in a GIS first?

Comment: if you're using "a shapefile that I found somewhere on the internet" I think your next step should be to find a different shapefile. Unless you know or can verify the source of the data you have no guarantees that it meets your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the shapefile in a GIS program and changed the area that is supposed to be water from a Polygon to a Poly-Line, which caused OpenMap to leave it as it is, instead of filing it with a color, which fixed the problem.